# Hibernate query count on multiple tabs

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have multiple tables :

1. vote
2. Question
3. Answer

Each of these tables have an authorId field.

I want to output this in an sql query :

MemberId1 . (Nbr of votes + Nbr of Question + Nbr of Answer )

MemberId2 . (Nbr of votes + Nbr of Question + Nbr of Answer )

MemberId3 . (Nbr of votes + Nbr of Question + Nbr of Answer )

How can I do this query with Hibernate criterias ?

In plain SQL I think it would be like this :

```
select sum(val) from (

select count(*) val from a

union all

select count(*) val from b

union all

select count(*) val from c

union all

select count(*) val from d )
```

Comment: why criteria? is it a dynamic query?

Comment: You should never ask hibernate query questions without providing information about your class model. With Hibernate, you are doing oop, so you don't care too much about tables but you highly depend on class structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, provided that you have mapped the one-to-many relationships between authors and the three entities in Author :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Author.class, "author");
criteria.createAlias("author.votes", "v", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("author.questions", "q", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("author.answers", "a", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("author.id"))
                                .add(Projections.countDistinct("v.id"))
                                .add(Projections.countDistinct("q.id"))
                                .add(Projections.countDistinct("a.id")));
```

**EDIT :**

But since the query is not dynamic, you should probably prefer HQL, which would allow you to write your query even if there's no mapping of the relationships in Author :

```
select author.id, count(distinct(v.id)), count(distinct(q.id)), count(distinct(a.id))
from Author author, Vote v, Question q, Answer a
where v.author.id = author.id
and   q.author.id = author.id
and   a.author.id = author.id
group by author.id
```

Comment: The thing is that I cant mapped the 1-n relationships because, in my firm we develop plugins which are not related to the Author.class, the Author.class must stay independant, so I cant map these relationships. Thats why i'm searching another way to do this query.

Comment: Then I think you won't be able to do it in Criteria, because Criteria only allows you to select from one root entity, and joins from this root entity. In HQL, you could do it. I'll update my answer.